# Solidity pragama not allowing for anything lower then 0.8.9

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

Hey I am currently starting on my first dapp but when I try and compile any of my code I get this error on hover on my

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
```

Error:

```
Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.8.9+commit.e5eed63a.Emscripten.clang) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
```

I can't deploy my contracts correctly any one know a fix?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the compiler version as expected 0.5.0 but you are set 0.8.9, That's the main reason for these errors.

[image]

It's perfectly working!

Answer (score 0):

You are compiling this with solc 0.8.9 and the pragma you are using says that solc 0.5.x is required.

To solve this simply use solc 0.5.17 (latest of the 0.5.x series). If you're using the compiler directly, you can get it from [solc-bin](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-bin/). If you are using a framework, you must set the compiler version you want in its configuration and it will download it automatically for you.